# Playing a wave file in QNX

Tags: multimedia, qnx

Can you please let me know how to play the wave file for the IMX 51 Multimedia board?The code is copied from the link as shown below:
http://www.qnx.org/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/audio/wavec.html

What are the arguments that needs to be given and where should the wave file be placed on the filesystem.

Advanced thanks
Maddy

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
wave /full/path/to/wavefile.wav
```

The same utility is present in your development environment under ${QNX_TARGET}/armle-v7/usr/bin/wave and includes use information:

```
bash-3.2$ use ./wave
wave Options] *

Options:
    -a[card#:]<dev#>   the card & device number to play out on
    -f<frag_size>      requested fragment size
    -v                 verbose
    -c<args>[,args ..] voice matrix configuration
    -n<num_frags>      requested number of fragments
    -p<volume in %>    volume in percent
    -m<mixer name>     string name for mixer input

Args:
    1=<hw_channel_bitmask> hardware channel bitmask for application voice 1
    2=<hw_channel_bitmask> hardware channel bitmask for application voice 2
    3=<hw_channel_bitmask> hardware channel bitmask for application voice 3
    4=<hw_channel_bitmask> hardware channel bitmask for application voice 4
```

(The above output was captured on 650 SP1.)